# Django template object property lookup with a dynamic variable name

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a table with user, rank, squat, deadlift, benchpress, Clean and Jerk and Snatch.

The ranking system will rank any number of combinations from just total amount Squated, to total amount benchpressed and deadlifted to the total amount lifted across all five disciplines. As you can see there is a huge number of available combinations that a user can check their rankings by. While i have as yet to painstakingly add all these ranking combinations to my database i have done the main 5 ie SQ_rank.

In my views file i have done the following, where request.GET gets either 'SQ', 'DL', 'BP', 'Snatch' or 'CJ':

```
def rankings()
    a = ''
    for i in request.GET:
        a += i    
    b = a + '_rank'    
    query_results = UserProfile.objects.all().order_by(a)
    rank = b
    return render_to_response('registration/rankings.html',{'query_results': query_results, 'rank': rank,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request, processors=[custom_proc]))
```

Now i want the rank as a variable inside of my template. it will return something _rank such as SQ_rank or DL_rank, which is in my database.

```
{% for item in query_results %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ item.user }}</td>
    <td>{{ items.??? }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.SQ }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.DL }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.BP }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.CJ }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.Snatch }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How do i do this without having a heap load of {% ifequal %}} tags accounting for all the varaible combinations that will be available when i get around to adding them to my database? Does all this make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

```
for i in request.GET:
```

is invalid since request.GET is a dict, not a list. If what you mean by item.??? is to lookup the item property whose name is contained in the "rank" variable, this is what I use for this purpose:

```
{{ item|ofKey:rank }}
```

The "ofKey" is a custom template filter. Create a file called, say, `extra.py` which contains:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def ofKey(value, arg):
    if value:
        return value.get(arg)
    else:
        return ""
```

Now save this file in a "templatetags" subdirectory of one of your app directories. You will need to use:

```
{% load extra %}
```

at the beginning of the templates where you will need it.

Comment: The loading of extra only works if i take out the "" as in {% load extra %}. I then get an error "Caught AttributeError while rendering: Manager isn't accessible via UserProfile instances" It then highlights the line "{% for item in query_results %}"

Comment: Ok, so "value" represents "item" which in turn represents an instance of a userprofile object. One must simply therefore check the functions native too the instance of userprofile object. One way of doing this quickly is just to type dir(value) in the extra.py return line. It will then output(untidly) the native functions. "get" is not there, but __getattribute__ is. Thus it now works. Thank You