# django template: custom template tag to display dictionary of dictionary

Tags: django, templates, dictionary

I want to do this in my template:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ realNameDict.field.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

realNameDict is a dictionary. The code above does not work. Why ?

**EDIT:** 
In python, I think I could do this :

```
print realNameDict[field[name]]
```

Many thanks.

## **SOLUTION:**

Thanks to the explanation of @Calvin Cheng:
The trick is to use custom template tags.

1/ In your application directory, create a directory called `templatetags`. Create two files: `__init__.py` (leave it empty) and `extra.py` (used to create the custom template tags).

2/ In extra.py, create the function to get the value of a dictionary of dictionary :

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def ofKey(value, arg):
    if value:
        return value.get(arg)
    else:
        return ""
```

3/In your template, inside the content block, add the following line to load the custom template tag:

```
{% load extra %}
```

4/ Call the custom template tag in your template:

```
{{ realNameDict|ofKey:field.name }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`realNameDict` does not know what `field` is. You are expecting the template for in loop to resolve the field value inside the dictionary but `realNameDict.field.name`'s `field` is actually literal field.

**Solution**

The trick is to write a custom template tag if you really insist on resolving `field` dynamically. Here's an example, a solution to a similar (not exactly the same) problem - [Django template object property lookup with a dynamic variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647966/django-template-object-property-lookup-with-a-dynamic-variable-name)

In this answer to a different question (but very similar to your problem), `ofKey` is a custom template tag function that dynamically resolves the `[variable]` in `item.[variable]`.

Meaning that you should have something like this:-

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field|resolve_realNameDict_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Because you do have the resolved value of `field` in your for-in loop, you can now use your custom template tag function `resolve_realNameDict_name` (*which you have to write yourself of course*) to act on the `field` as it loops through the for-in loop and return the appropriate `name` value from your custom template tag function into the template.

Comment: Ok. So how to do? I have edited my first post to explain what I want to do.